# How do I create a zoom slider for a bokeh animation?

Tags: python-3.x, animation, widget, bokeh

I want to have slider widget to zoom in and out of a bokeh animation. The slider should zoom to a specific point in the figure (for example (100,123)) and have a maximum and minimum zoom level.
I am using curdoc() and bokeh server.

I was wondering how someone with more experience would do that.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple example which you can further customise and improve. Position your point of interest in the middle e.g. (50, 50) and move the slider. This code works for Bokeh v1.0.4

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, curdoc
from bokeh.models import Slider, CustomJS, Range1d
from bokeh.layouts import column

slider_zoom = Slider(title = 'Zoom', start = -12, end = 8, value = 0, step = 1)
zoom_value = slider_zoom.value

x = np.linspace(-40, 40, 200)
y = x

p = figure(title = "Zoom Slider", plot_height = 500, plot_width = 600, y_range = Range1d(start = -40, end = 40), background_fill_color = '#efefef')
r = p.line(x, y, color = "red", line_width = 1.5, alpha = 0.8)
r = p.circle(x, y, color = "blue", line_width = 0.5, alpha = 0.8)

last_value = None

def update(attr, old, new):
    global last_value
    if last_value is not None:
        if new > 0:
            if new > last_value:
                p.y_range.start = p.y_range.start + new
                p.y_range.end = p.y_range.end - new

                p.x_range.start = p.x_range.start + new
                p.x_range.end = p.x_range.end - new
            else:
                p.y_range.start = p.y_range.start - new
                p.y_range.end = p.y_range.end + new

                p.x_range.start = p.x_range.start - new
                p.x_range.end = p.x_range.end + new
        elif new < 0:
            if new < last_value:
                p.y_range.start = p.y_range.start + new
                p.y_range.end = p.y_range.end - new

                p.x_range.start = p.x_range.start + new
                p.x_range.end = p.x_range.end - new
            else:
                p.y_range.start = p.y_range.start - new
                p.y_range.end = p.y_range.end + new

                p.x_range.start = p.x_range.start - new
                p.x_range.end = p.x_range.end + new

    last_value = new

slider_zoom.on_change('value', update)

layout = column(p, slider_zoom)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Result:

[image]